# Result Object instead of out parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, error-handling, out

A co-worker of mine brought up an interesting thought, but we are both a little unsure about the complications that could arise.

Currently most of our methods have an 'out' parameter to return a list of messages(success, error, etc.). Like so...

```
public bool Delete(int id, out List<UIMessage> uiMessages)
{
    //Delete stuff
    bool wasDeleteSuccessful = //set bool here
    List<UIMessages> uiMessages = //Set messages here

    return wasDeleteSuccessful
}
```

We are considering the idea of returning a new object that would have a T type property and a List property. Like so...

```
public ResultObject<bool> Delete(int id)
{
    //Delete stuff
    bool wasDeleteSuccessful = //set bool here
    List<UIMessages> uiMessages = //Set messages here

    return new ResultObject<bool>(wasDeleteSuccessful, uiMessages)
}
```

I'm pretty sure the only benefit here is that we don't have to deal with 'out' parameters, but what drawbacks are we not considering?

Comment: This idea is not new one. Check [this](https://gist.github.com/vkhorikov/7852c7606f27c52bc288#file-result-cs) implementation and use case.

Comment: Considering `List<>` is a reference type, the caller can safely pass in an initialized instance and the method would then just add to it. Just an alternative.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Oh, right... that makes sense

Comment: Some people are OK with `out` parameters, some aren't. I would say this is just a cleaner way to do what you're already doing. I won't flag this as primarily opinion based, as it does ask about *potential* problems, but keep in mind that your question is a little abstract.

Comment: @GediminasMasaitis I am aware that this is bordering on opinion based, but like you said, it is a question about potential complications, and I am unsure where I would ask this type of question other wise. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @user2023116 I'd say [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is a more apropriate sister site for questions regarding software design practices.

Comment: It strikes me as pretty odd that your delete object has any sort of message at all.  The only scenario where I would expect such an API would be in a public-facing API method (to make it easier to diagnose failures).

Comment: @Brian It is so that I can pass back a message for the user to know weather or not the delete was successful or not, and an appropriate message as to why. Reasons for failure that the user might want to know are that permission was denied, or to show a "friendly" data base error message. Is this an uncommon approach?

Comment: @user2023116: In a public-facing API, this approach is pretty common.  In a private application (i.e., where the function was implemented by an employee or coworker of the user), I would consider this approach less appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally preferable to return values rather than mutating variables. By returning values rather than mutating variables you gain the ability to use your method in contexts in which you must not mutated variables. Consider for example: deletion is a prime candidate for asynchrony because it might be a high-latency operation. A method that mutates a caller's variable is very difficult to make asynchronous.

However, this would be a good time to step back and ask if you are actually doing the right thing in the first place. The contract of this method seems bizarre. I would expect a method which deletes something to return void, because deletion is an effect, not the production of a value. I would expect that in the event of failure, the failure state would be stored in a thrown exception, not in a list of messages.

Comment: I don't consider it bizarre for a deletion method to return bool; that approach is common in sets (e.g., [HashSet<T>.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342694.aspx), since the user only cares that the collection excludes the object, not that the object was removed.  It's also common in concurrent collections.

Comment: @EricLippert if failure for deletion was a common (not exceptional) scenario, would you still recommend using exceptions or maybe returning an object with the failure reason? I say this because I more and more see the "trend" of people using exceptions to control the flow of normal plausible operations (maybe deletion is a bad example), and I hate that, but other than "for performance reasons" (which is a bit tiny not real in non-debug modes) or using the semantic "exceptions should be exceptions, not correct operations that did not complete", I don't have an argument for that

Answer (score 1):

No major drawback, just unnecessary additional complexity with new result object which contains completely the same information as the previous implementation with `out` parameter. If those methods get executed a lot, you might be better of (performance and memory wise) with less objects being instantiated and thus with your first (out) implementation.

I would personally prefer the out implementation in the given example, because your method tends to follow [try-parse pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009(v=vs.110).aspx). Try-parse pattern informs you of the success by returning the bool and gives you the result/info objects in out parameters. Your naming is in such case a bit wrong. Instead of Delete, it would be better to name the method TryDelete

Answer (score 0):

Check out [DomainResult](https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult) NuGet package that provides a solution for that problem (requires .NET Standard 2).

At its core it has `IDomainResult` (similar to yours `ResultObject`) with properties:

```cs
IReadOnlyCollection<string> Errors { get; } // Collection of error messages if any
bool IsSuccess { get; }                     // Flag, whether the current status is successful or not
DomainOperationStatus Status { get; }       // Current status of the domain operation: Success, Error, NotFound
```

And from here you've got 2 options for returned object in your method:

1. A generic `IDomainResult<T>` that extends the one above by adding `T Value { get; }` property.
2. Return [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple) from methods, like `(T, IDomainResult)`.

It all is spiced up with 50+ extension methods, e.g.

```cs
// Successful result with an int
(value, state) = IDomainResult.Success(10);        // value = 10; state.Status is 'Success'
// The same but wrapped in a task
var res = IDomainResult.SuccessTask(10);           // res is Task<(int, IDomainResult)>

// Error message
IDomainResult = IDomainResult.Error("Ahh!");       // res.Status is 'Error' and res.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
// Error when expected an int
(value, state) = IDomainResult.Error<int>("Ahh!"); // value = 0, state.Status is 'Error' and state.Errors = new []{ "Ahh!" }
```

Examples would be:

```cs
public async Task<(InvoiceResponseDto, IDomainResult)> GetInvoice(int invoiceId)
{
    if (invoiceId < 0)
        // Returns a validation error
        return IDomainResult.Error<InvoiceResponseDto>("Try harder");

    var invoice = await DataContext.Invoices.FindAsync(invoiceId);
    
    if (invoice == null)
        // Returns a Not Found response
        return IDomainResult.NotFound<InvoiceResponseDto>();

    // Returns the invoice
    IDomainResult.Success(invoice);
}
```

or if you're against [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple), then a more traditional method signature:

```cs
public async Task<IDomainResult<InvoiceResponseDto>> GetInvoice(int invoiceId)
{
    if (invoiceId < 0)
        // Returns a validation error
        return DomainResult.Error<InvoiceResponseDto>("Try harder");
    ...
}
```

It also has 20+ extensions to convert the `IDomainResult`-based types to corresponding `IActionResult` for returning from WebAPI controller methods.

Check out the samples at https://github.com/AKlaus/DomainResult. It all yours.